# Escaner fisico conectarlo a un proyecto de asp.net

Tags: mvc

Compre un escaner (barcore scanner MJ-8200) y quisiera sugerencias para utilizarlo dentro de un proyecto, ya sea asp, o mvc, con algún script, cualquier  sugerencia gracias.

Comment: Por lo general no necesitas nada para utilizarlo dentro de un proyecto, ya que los barcode scanner lo que hace, por lo general, es escribir el texto que escaneó (código de barras) en la pc (como si lo tipeases), y luego presiona la tecla enter